# Extending Meteor.loginWith

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I am looking to create my own custom Meteor.loginWith call using an Account API that the company I work for maintains. I am successfully making calls to it's Authenticate and User API's to get all the information I need, but ideally I would like to base my userId and token information off the account server and not Meteor's implementation. I know this exists for services like Facebook, Google, etc, but how do I add my custom call?

Alternatively, just knowing how to overwrite a user's userId would work as well.

Comment: The Facebook login implementation for Meteor actually stores the Facebook ID in a different field, and _id is still the default generated Mongo ID.

Comment: Which won't work for me. I need the id's to sync up.

Comment: Its @stubailo said, Meteor does not store Facebook or Google ids under userId. For a good reason. Instead those are stored under services in the user document. I would recommend that you do the same.

Comment: So how would I log the user in if I had no way to know their userId. I can't search for a user by profile.Id can I?

Comment: Have you figured out how to do it? I am facing the same issue. The problem is plugging into the existing Meteor login flow, so Meteor.currentUser etc still works.

Comment: No, I have not been working with meteor recently, as it was not a good fit for current work projects. I am planning to get back into this more once I am finish learning Cordova, but until then I have nothing to report on this. Sorry :/